# Autoincrement a composite key in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, max, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a table that uses a composite primary key. The idea is that we have an order "number" (string) and a line number (integer). When inserting into the table, the order number will be known, but there is no known or assigned line number; I want that to be automatically generated as the lowest line number for that order number.

I've tried using a composite primary key(orderNumber, lineNumber) and putting NULL for the lineNumber, both with and without the lineNumber field set to NOT NULL. I've also tried using AUTOINCREMENT on lineNumber, however, that just gives me a syntax error.

The program I'm writing is using c++, so I mean worst case I could query the orderNumber myself and calculate the lineNumber to insert before inserting a row, but that seems like it would not be the optimal choice. Any suggestions?

Example data:

| orderNumber | SKU | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | xyz | etc |
| def456 | xyz | etc |
| abc123 | wxc | etc |
| ghi645 | wxc | etc |
| abc123 | hk4 | etc |
| def456 | hk4 | etc |

After inserting these rows in the table, it should be

| orderNumber | lineNumber | SKU | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 1 | xyz | etc |
| def456 | 1 | xyz | etc |
| abc123 | 2 | wxc | etc |
| ghi645 | 1 | wxc | etc |
| abc123 | 3 | hk4 | etc |
| def456 | 2 | hk4 | etc |

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Do you want this as a new column in the table? What will happen if you delete a row? This should be done with a SELECT query. Also, do you have a column that denotes the order of the rows? Tables are unordered datasets. There is no first, next, previous or last row.

Comment: Ummmm well this is an entirely new database, so i guess it'd be a new column? Not sure what you mean by that. If a row is deleted, ideally use the now-removed line number, but if that's too hard then just using the next line after the highest is perfectly fine.

I don't see why a column for the order of the rows would matter - that would be handled by the sorting on the select query.

Comment: I guess what you're suggesting is on insertion, run a select statement for orderNumber, get the highest contiguous lineNumber from the set, increment that by 1, and then insert? I was hoping there was a more efficient way than doing that, but if that's what has to happen, that's how it'll be.

Comment: I mean if you delete the row with (abc123, 2) you will be left with rows (abc123,1) and (abc123,3).

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this, like an autoincrement column.

You can insert each row with a `SELECT` statement that counts the rows of the table with the same `orderNumber`:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(orderNumber, lineNumber, SKU, ....)
SELECT 'abc123', COALESCE(MAX(lineNumber), 0) + 1, 'xyz', .... 
FROM tablename 
WHERE orderNumber = 'abc123';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bffd7dfbe6b9e1b64652f883da51d7ee).

Comment: Wouldn't using COUNT(\*) + 1 create errors if a line got deleted? Would replacing that with MAX(\*) + 1 work?

Comment: @Merddyn This is why I asked in the comments, if there would be a problem when you delete a row. I will edit with MAX() and check the result in the demo.

Comment: Oh that's weird, I didn't know you could nest SQL statements like that. Let me just make sure I'm understanding the syntax right - the SELECT 'abc123', COALESCE(MAX(lineNumber), 0) + 1, 'xyz', .... 
FROM tablename 
WHERE orderNumber = 'abc123'; returns a row that is 'abc123, (first non-null value of the highest line number for order 'abc123' from the where statement or 0 if there is none) +1 ,'xyz', and then the INSERT INTO function gets called being, passed the values in that row (with each column being a separate parameter)?

Comment: @Merddyn yes, this is how it works. The SELECT statement always returns exactly 1 row because of the aggregate function MAX().

Comment: Oh, I'd tried to do that by the upvote thing and didn't notice the checkmark. Thank you for your help!!!